# How do I make text in a flexbox hidden and then make it appear when the flexbox item is hovered over?

Tags: css, flexbox, hover, hidden

I want the black text in the box (I choose Medellin) to be hidden but when I mouse over the actual grid item I want it to appear.  How is this possible?

```
<main id="cards">
        <a href="signup.html"><section class="cards__med">
            <div class="cards__flexchild">
                <h1 class="cards__med-title">Medellín</h1>
                <img class="cards__medimage" src="img/medellin.jpeg" alt="medellin">
                <h1 class="cards__texthead">The City of Eternal Spring</h1>
                
                <!-- <a href="signup.html" class="cards__med-btn">Choose City</a> -->
                <h1>I choose Medellín!</h1>
            </div>
        </section></a>
    
   #cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
        -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 3rem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem :)

You'd want to avoid using multiple H1s on a page to maintain the document outline but you can simple use something such as:

// If you just want a simple hide / show
.cards__med:not(:hover) .cards__med-btn { display:none; }

I'd also try to clean the HTML up a little bit if at all possible as there are multiple nested elements that will throw validation errors and multiple h1s:

```
<div href="signup.html" class="cards__med cards__flexchild">
      <h1 class="cards__med-title">Medellín</h1>
      <img class="cards__medimage" src="img/medellin.jpeg" alt="medellin">
       <h2 class="cards__texthead">The City of Eternal Spring</h2>
                
       <a href="signup.html" class="cards__med-btn">Choose City</a>
</div>
``
```

Comment: After much frustration trying to get the rest of my code in, that all worked.  Green checkmark for you sir!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on which element in the HTML it is you want to be hidden but you can adapt the following as you see fit:

### CSS

```
.selector:not(:hover) .item-reveal {
  opacity:0; // If you want the area the hidden content will occupy to stay the same height
  display:none; // If you want to completely hide the element
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I got the wrong code put in, it's actually a flexbox not a grid